# mod_rewrite virtual directories without variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I haven't come up with a solution for this. I want to have multiple virtual directories but cant find how to do it without using PHP or some sort of variables. For example I want:

```
mysite.com/restaurant/ to point to mysite.com/restaurant.php

mysite.com/restaurant/menu/ to point to mysite.com/restaurant-menu.php
mysite.com/restaurant/location/ to point to mysite.com/restaurant-location.php
```

And so on, there is no dynamic content; I have all the files.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `mod_rewrite` to do that!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^restaurant/?$  restaurant.php [L]
RewriteRule ^restaurant/menu/?$  restaurant-menu.php [L]
RewriteRule ^restaurant/location/?$  restaurant-location.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but Im getting an error, up until here things work:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^restaurant/?$  restaurant.php [L]

But when I add the next line 
RewruteRule ^restaurant/menu/?$  restaurant-menu.php [L]
I get 500 Internal server error, and even the /restaurant/ link that worked previously stops doing so.

Comment: @Hacienda Misne soory, check it out!

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be: `RewriteRule ^restaurant/location/?$  restaurant-location.php [L]`? You could also replace the last 2 with `RewriteRule ^restaurant/([^/]*)/?$ restaurant-$1.php [L]` if there are more virtual directories.